# Dm-crypt: who can see data?

Tags: linux, filesystems, dm-crypt

I'm starting to investigate on Dm-crypt concept and usage on several Linux servers.
I saw how should I configure it, there are several guides on web. Unfortunately I'm finding any information regarding my doubt:

1. Who will be able to read files content? Only who will access using ssh?

Answer (score 0):

1. Anyone with physical access to the server (since it's possible to read RAM directly using DMA hacks).
2. Anyone already on the server, i.e. each running application if it has the required permissions.
3. Anyone with SSH credentials again given they have the required permissions.

Comment: Thank you, really. You confirm my doubts, so.... Dm-crypt will prevent data fraud in which situations? Sorry, my questions is probably trivial I know.

Comment: In no ways it can directly help prevent data fraud.

Comment: Is there a reason I should use it?

Comment: People use it usually on home computers/laptops, to prevent data theft/loss/leak. Android uses it as well for the same reasons.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your answers